# Trying to make a local file dictionary and search system

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a local file searcher, which will search for files based on tags, and also will by names. i dont have any idea on how to make the searching system nor the python dictionary and searching with tags which confuse me.

```
files = {'samplefile1.txt', 'samplefile2.txt'}

fileName = ''
fileDiscription = 'Enter Discription here'
isMP3File = True
isMP4File = True
isTxtFile = True
isArchived = True
tags = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'favorited']

filesDictionary = {
    'samplefile1.txt': {
        fileName: 'coolFile1',
        fileDiscription: 'cool disc.',
        isMP3File: False,
        isMP4File: False,
        isTxtFile: True,
        isArchived: False,
        tags = ['sample1', 'favorited']
    },
    'samplefile1.txt': {
        fileName: 'coolFile2',
        fileDiscription: 'cool disc2',
        isMP3File: False,
        isMP4File: False,
        isTxtFile: True,
        isArchived: True,
        tags = ['sample2']
    },
}
```

so in the code above, with search function, it should show only samplefile1.txt when searched by 'sample1', or 'favorited', or samplefile2.txt if searched with 'sample2'

(also fileName is the name i was talking about in this question, not the file name on pc)
(also any idea on how to automate this 'files' dictionary adding using gui (something like how you would post stuff to twitter or smth, with ticks and message boxes))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a coding service, your question is out of scope as it is right now. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: your files dictionary has a repeated key `'samplefile1.txt'`. You cannot have reapeated keys in dictionaries

Comment: whoops sorry i was just making it up will change one of it

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary where you have each tag as a key, and the filename as a value.
Since you want to search by tag, having the tags as keys will make the search time constant.

```
searchDict = {
    'sample1': ['samplefile1.txt'],
    'favorited': ['samplefile1.txt'],
    'sample2': ['samplefile2.txt']
}
```

then given a tag you can just get the filename inmediately

```
searchDict['sample1']   # will return ['samplefile1.txt']
```

You can then use that key to access your main dictionary files

```
for filename in searchDict['sample1']:
    print(files[filename])
```

will print

```
{
    fileName: 'coolFile1',
    fileDiscription: 'cool disc.',
    isMP3File: False,
    isMP4File: False,
    isTxtFile: True,
    isArchived: False,
    tags = ['sample1', 'favorited']
}
```

To create the searchDict, you can iterate once over your database of files, getting the tags and associating them to the filenames. It will be a costly operation if your database is big, but once done your search will run in constant time.